# Aren't the definitions of zero point energy and the 3rd law of the thermodynamics contradictory?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I was listening to a statistical mechanics lecture, and my professor started talking about zero point energy. He defined it as the energy a particle has at 0 K. Doesn't this violate the 3rd law of the thermodynamics? I'm wondering if anyone can clarify, I have searched the term zero point energy with little success.

Comment: The third law describes what happens at $0$ K while zero point energy merely implies $0$ K is unobtainable. I see no contradiction.

Comment: But doesn't the scale measure kinetic energy? Absolute zero would require zero energy so how can zero point energy be a nonzero term? Maybe zero point energy doesn't have to be of the kinetic quality...?

Comment: As far as I know third law does not always hold and does not deserve to be called a law,it is applicable to only few nicely engineered system not all kind of systems.  :).

Comment: @lemon the fact that $0 K$ is unattainable has nothing to do with the existence or absence of zero point energy.

Answer (score -3):

In the context of particles, the zero point energy it is not really a measure of a particle's energy *per se*, but a measure of our uncertainty about that energy. Even if we were to declare that a particle had zero energy, we would have no way to prove that; any measurement to confirm that figure is subject to the uncertainty principle, which is quite apparent at these sorts of energy scales.

Its not entirely unlike a thermometer that has some random continual motion in the pointer. You'll never know, beyond that random motion, what the energy of the object you're measuring is. The key difference here is that the randomness depends on the *thing you're measuring*, which is not the case with macroscopic thermometers.

You'll note that the 3rd law says that the entropy of a *system* becomes fixed as you approach 0K, the statement doesn't really apply to single particles. But even in particle systems, the idea that the entropy will approach a fixed value as the temperature approaches "the minimum possible" sounds perfectly fine to my ears.

Comment: "Even if we were to declare that a particle had zero energy, we would have no way to prove that" - but we can certainly *dis*prove it because zero energy would correspond to a prohibitively localised wave-function. So zero point energy is more than a mere uncertainty about energy.

Comment: In that case its an uncertainty about the position/momentum then. It's still the same principle underlying both statements, no?

Comment: There is a difference, although it's subtle. The role of uncertainty is to prohibit the ZPE from being zero. However, the ZPE itself has a precise value and it's a real energy - it's not merely a measure of uncertainty about the energy.

Comment: Unless I am greatly mistaken, you're talking about the *other* ZPE, the energy of the vacuum. That is not the same thing.

Comment: Nope, this applies directly to QM wave-functions in crystals. In fact, calculations of crystal free energies include an explicit ZPE contribution.